# dictionary conversion from reading files in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

What is the difference between line number 5 and line number 6?
line number 5 throws error but line number 6 works. I am unable to understand the difference.

```
 with open("file1.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    print(dict(line.split('=', 1))) # Line 5 throwing ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required


    
print(dict(line.split('=', 1) for line in lines)) # Line 6 works fine
```

Comment: Please update your question with some sample lines from `"file1.txt"`.

Comment: please format correctly i.e add comments instead of mis-indentation. Is line 5 in the for loop block?

Comment: `dict` expects an iterable of tuples of (key, value), but you only provide a list of two values `[key, value`]. `print(dict([line.split('=', 1)]))` works as the `[key, value]` pair is now in a list.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have values like the following for `lines`:

```
lines = ["foo=bar", "baz=ola"]
```

In this code:

```
print(dict(line.split('=', 1) for line in lines))
```

the argument to `dict` is an iterable of lists of two elements, similar to:

```
>>> dict([["foo", "bar"], ["baz", "ola"]])
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'ola'}
```

In this code:

```
for line in lines:
    print(dict(line.split('=', 1)))
```

we call `dict()` multiple times, each time with a list of two elements, similar to:

```
>>> dict(["foo", "bar"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

"Dictionary update sequence element #0" is `"foo"`; each "sequence element" is a key, value pair, so the error is happening because `dict()` is trying to interpret `"foo"` as if it were a pair.  Since your error message indicates "length 1", I'm guessing your file has a one-character name in it that is similarly being interpreted as a pair.

If we used two-character strings, it would "work", but it would work by using the first character as the key and the second character as the value:

```
>>> line = "ab=xy"
>>> dict(line.split("="))
{'a': 'b', 'x': 'y'}
```

The key takeaway is that the argument to `dict` must be *all the key, value pairs*, not a *single* key, value pair -- i.e. it must be a generator, list, or other iterable that contains *other* iterables with exactly two elements each.  Even if you only have a single pair, you must put that pair inside an iterable (e.g. a list), because `dict()` will *always* treat its argument as an iterable of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is the answer:

> If no positional argument is given, an empty dictionary is created. If
> a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a
> dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping
> object. Otherwise, **the positional argument must be an iterable object.
> Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two
> objects.** The first object of each item becomes a key in the new
> dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

In line 6 you have an iterator whose items are an iterable with two objects. Line 5 is just a list with two items.

Answer (score 0):

For a file like:

```
x=1
y=2
z=3
```

Use something like the following:

```py
with open('f.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()  # strips newlines

new_dict = dict([line.split('=') for line in lines])
```

The list comprehension inside the call to `dict` produces a list where each element of the list are the split components of the lines.  In this case:

```py
[['x', '1'], ['y', '2'], ['z', '3']]
```

The `dict` function consumes iterables like this (with elements consisting of 2 elements) as key-value pairs.

If you inspect `new_dict` you'd see:

```py
print(new_dict)
{'x': '1', 'y': '2', 'z': '3'}
```